# Using 32 bit interop dll in 64 bit application

Tags: c#, com, interop, 32bit-64bit, rcw

I am little confused about using 32 bit interop dll with 64 bit process.
In order to get access to 8TB of memory I am going to build my application for 64 bit, unfortunately it uses some statistical interop library which is build in 32 bit mode. I don't have sources for this library so I cannot rebuild it to 64 bit.

In [this](http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/) article the suggestion is to create 64 bit surrogate process that will communicate with my app using IPC (e.g. WCF). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875112/64-to-32-bit-interop-how) we can find the solution that uses Runtime Callable Wrapper ([RCW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). Which is better? I started to implement surrogate process and just today I found the second solution which I don't know if is suitable for my needs.

I need to mention that this statistical interop library has hundreds of interfaces and classes. Still I need just some of them. I have started creating WCF service hosting several of them as endpoints and it seems it will be a lot of code/work.

Can I use second method (RCW) to use with interop dll?

Regards,
jotbek

Comment: I'd probably opt for COM, but there's probably not much between any of these options. Which is most convenient and easy for you? Now, in your position I'd strongly contemplate losing the dependency on this 3rd party library. I always like to build from source and a dependency on a black box that only exists in 32 bit code would give me the fear. There are oodles of good statistical libraries around. Can't you find one that is more future proof?

Comment: Unfortunately main point is to use this library. So you think it is not a problem to use RCW solution for Interop dll?

Comment: We don't know your perf requirements. RPC can have perf. implications. But if they are not significant, then use whatever RPC works for you. Very hard to imagine that there's only one lib that meets your needs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Lets pretend that this is only library that may be used, actually it was created for specific needs of this application. I was rather curious if there will be no problem with using RCW for Interop dll rather than regular COM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, "better" is a loaded term.  But, yes, COM surrogates can make it a helluvalot simpler to get this going.  If you can use the system surrogate, odds are almost always good when the library was well designed, then you just need to duplicate the registry keys into the 64-bit keys and tweak a few of them to use the surrogate and it all works without you writing any code at all.  The MSDN starting page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695225%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It won't work out when the library doesn't support cross apartment marshaling.  If you have no idea if it does then try calling a library function from a worker thread.  If that doesn't work then don't bother trying.  And you'll lose the "better" if this library is prone to crashing bugs, that invariably turns out poorly in an out-of-process scenario.  Speed might be an issue, out-of-process calls have a lot of overhead.  But you're stuck with that either way.  You'll get good answers instead of SO guesses by contacting the library owner for support.