# Using a 32bit COM-object in a 64bit environment

Tags: c#, .net, com, 32bit-64bit, com-interop

The code below executes without problems in a 32bit c#-application.

```
 object obj = system.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Due.Application");

 var due = (Due.IDueApplication2)obj;
```

Now, I try to get the same code working in a 64bit c#-application and therefore I followed the instructions at

http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/ or http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/267554/Using-bit-COM-Object-from-bit-Application

Two cases when running the 64bit application

1. *Due* **is not** running and the first code-line fails with `HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE)`. **That's fine** and happens in the 32bit version as well.
2. *Due* **is** running and in the first code-line `obj` receives a COM-object. But then, the second code-line throws an `InvalidCastException` because `QueryInterface` fails with `HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)`. (Obviously, this works in the 32bit version.)

**Q** What must I do, to make the cast in the 2nd code-line to succeed?

**Edit** As suggested by @HansPassant, I fired up the ProcessMonitor and monitored both the 32bit and 64bit application. I observed that the 64bit application when executing `GetActiveObject` (1st code-line) omitted accessing a COM-object specific dll (CreateFile, QueryBasicInformationFile, QueryNameInformationFile, ...) which in contrast the 32bit application did, even though I've added the according registry entries beforehand, i.e. `AppID`, `DllSurrogate`.

**Edit1** I removed all the registry-entries I added and double-checked the results including the log-files of the ProcessMonitor. I didn't notice any difference - same symptoms as before.

**Update** In the directory of the 3rd party software I found a `Due.tlb` and I tried to create a runtime-callable-wrapper as hinted in [64 to 32 bit Interop - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6443055).

I created an `Interop.due.dll` with `tlbimp.exe Due.tlb /out:Interop.due.dll`. Unfortunately, when I replaced the original 32-bit `Interop.deu.dll` with the newly created platform-agnostic one my solution failed to compile (missing references).

Comment: Hmm, 0x80040154 is pretty odd.  But surely the problem is that you don't have a 64-bit version of the proxy.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to get insight.

Comment: If you vote down, please leave a comment why.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried the ProcessMonitor, please see my edit for the results.

Comment: Well, that doesn't help much.  Not mentioning in your question that you've edited the registry by hand and tinkered with surrogates is pretty criminal btw.  You did it wrong, nobody can possibly know what you did wrong when you don't describe it.

Comment: @HansPassant Remember the two links I referenced in my original post, that's what I've tried to get things going.

Comment: Maybe it's a VirtualStore problem? It could be possible that you created the registry keys right. But Windows looks for them inside the VirtualStore. Just as an idea.

Comment: @user743414 Probably not, because I did the editing with admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which worked was an out-of-process solution. I implemented a [32-bit WCF-service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx) which provides the access to the COM-objects for the 64-bit process. (Hence, I implemented the proxy myself.)

**ad Update**

*good news*

By utilizing the information in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30737774/4090370) I was able to regenerate a platform agnostic version of the `Interop.due.dll`. Even though, `TlbImp.exe` warned me with *warning TI3002 : Importing a type library into a platform agnostic assembly.  This can cause errors if the type library is not truly platform agnostic.*

*bad news*

The promised *glue code* was not provided and therefore the bridging of 64bit and 32bit did not work out. (The 32bit only version worked as before.)