# Does OPOS works only for x86 .NET applications?

Tags: c#, .net, barcode-scanner, opos

I was trying to interface with OPOS interface a DataLogic-QuickScan-QD2131 handheld scanner using the following code:

```
class Program 
{
    static OposScanner_CCO.OPOSScanner scanner;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        scanner = new OposScanner_CCO.OPOSScanner();
        scanner.Open("USBHHScanner");
        scanner.ClaimDevice(1000);

        if (scanner.Claimed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Claimed succesfully");
            scanner.DeviceEnabled = true;
            scanner.DataEventEnabled = true;
            scanner.DecodeData = true;
            scanner.FreezeEvents = false;
            scanner.DataEvent += Scanner_DataEvent;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Scanner_DataEvent(int Status)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scanned {0}", Status);
    }
}
```

When I'm compiling this program targeting "Any CPU" this wouldn't  work, throwing exception at the first line of Main:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {CCB90182-B81E-11D2-AB74-0040054C3719} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

But when compiles to x86 it sort of working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [opos tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/opos/info) in stackoverflow says it is win32-based devices, so I guess it makes sense if the tag is correct. BTW, not adding an answer because I have never used opos and I may be wrong

Comment: Windows provide special tricks to help utilize 32bit COM objects from 64 bit application. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601032/using-a-32bit-com-object-in-a-64bit-environment and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043954/how-to-use-a-32-bit-com-object-on-windows-server-2008-works-on-2008-r2-but-non

Comment: @Serg Even if technically possible, the vendor will not support it due to commercial warranty issues.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, most OPOS works only in 32-bit mode.

It was the time when OPOS was born without 64-bit mode, the Common CO was created only for 32bit, and many of the OPOS service objects are still created in VC++, etc. It is influencing.

It seems that some vendors create 64-bit CO based on the Common CO source code, and at the same time create and combine 64-bit SO to support 64-bit mode, but that is only a proprietary offer. Probably.

---

Mr. Curtiss Monroe, who was in charge of development, update and maintenance of Common CO, has stopped updating UnifiedPOS(OPOS) after v1.14.1.
[Monroe Consulting Services](http://monroecs.com/index.htm)
The Common CO up to that version is provided only in 32-bit mode.

Therefore, I am updating the Common CO for both 32bit/64bit environments based on the Common CO source from UnifiedPOS(OPOS) v1.15.
[kunif/OPOS-CCO](https://github.com/kunif/OPOS-CCO)
So far, it has been recognized by the OPOS-J Technical Council in Japan.

---

Various data registered in the registry are important in the COM environment, but they are separated in the 32-bit environment and the 64-bit environment.
If you do not take special care in the program, you will not be able to cooperate with each other in 32bit/64bit.

Therefore, in order to use OPOS in a 64-bit environment, it is necessary for the device vendor to create and provide a service object for the 64-bit environment.

Even in that case, each component of 32bit/64bit cannot be mixed in one program.
Mixing 32bit/64bit in one program will require all applications/CO/SO to deal with it.
It's unrealistic.

---

For that reason, until now only OPOS that operates in 32-bit mode has been offered.

Until the vendor of each device accepts my (or someone else's) 64-bit Common CO and provides a service object for 64-bit mode, OPOS will not change the situation where it only works in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Thank you! very appreciate your detailed answer!